# Regex for date evaluates to true even with wrong characters

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be pretty easy, however I'm pretty new to regex so please excuse my stupidity.

I evaluate a date with the jQuery Validation plugin using a regex. This all works pretty great. However if the user uses Slashes instead of Dots for seperation it also evaluates to true.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "deDateTime",
         function (value, element) {
            //dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
            var re = /^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}$/;
            return (this.optional(element) && value == "") || re.test(value);
        },
        "Bitte geben sie ein Datum im Format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' an."
        );
```

Example:

```
re.Test("12.10.2014 18:00"); //True as it is supposed to be
re.Test("12/10/2014 18:00"); //Also true. Shouldn't be.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot is [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in a regular expression. Replace all your dots with escaped dots : `\.`

Comment: Oh well. Easy it was. Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion : take a few (dozens) minutes browsing the site I linked to.